# Not sorting an array with bubble sorting

Tags: java, sorting

Sorry for the beginner question, I faced a problem sorting an array using bubble sorting:

```java
class Search {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int temp;
        boolean fixed = false;
        while (fixed = false) {
            fixed = true;
            int number[] = {6, 7, 3, 2, 9};
            for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
                if (number[i] > number[i + 1]) {
                    temp = number[i + 1];
                    number[i + 1] = number[i];
                    number[i] = temp;
                    fixed = false;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(number[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: What problem occurred? What is your desired and actual output?

Comment: `while(fixed=false)` maybe should be `while(fixed==false)` or even better as `while(!fixed)`

Comment: @maloomeister the desired output is to sort the array from bigger to small, but I receive blank output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thank you, but now I receive this: 9
 6
 3
 2
 7 in loop

Comment: Please add all this information to the question, so that users do not have to read comments to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition problem (fixed = false) which is always true, your should print your result after your loop and you sorted the numbers wrong (small to bigger, you intended the other way). You also need to define your array outside the loop.

```
int temp;
boolean fixed=false;
int number[]= {6, 7, 3, 2, 9 };
while(!fixed) {
    fixed = true;
    for(int i=0; i<number.length-1; i++) {
        if(number[i] < number[i+1]) {
            temp = number[i + 1];
            number[i+1] = number[i];
            number[i] = temp;
            fixed = false;
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i < number.length; i++)    {
    System.out.println(number[i]);
}
```

Comment: Another error you corrected but didn't mention is, that he had the initialization of `number[]` in the while loop, which also caused an inifinite loop.

Comment: Still it is not solving the infinite loop issue

Comment: @anuragsaxena It does. while(!fixed) is the same as while(fixed == false), just shorter.

Answer (score -1):

1. 1)Fixed  while (fixed == false)

2. Fixed array initialization
   outside while loop
3. added sysout outside of while loop

public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp;
        boolean fixed = false;
        int number[] = {6, 7, 3, 2, 9};
        while (fixed == false) {
            fixed = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
                if (number[i] > number[i + 1]) {
                    temp = number[i + 1];
                    number[i + 1] = number[i];
                    number[i] = temp;
                    fixed = false;
                }
            }


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(number[i]);
        }

    }
```

Output:
2
3
6
7
9